# Intra-Organization Consenus in Hyperledger-fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need to execute a particular transaction with the consent of 3 peers from different departments inside a particular organization how would I do about it with Hyperledger-fabric

Comment: need to better understand what you mean by "users". Basically, the way endorsement works is that endorsing nodes simulate a chaincode transaction, capture the read and write sets for the transaction and sign the result. There isn't any provision for a user "approving" as a function of the chaincode execution. 

The closest thing we have for that would be the process for collecting signatures on a transaction to modify the channel block to upgrade the chaincode or add new member(s).

Comment: Ok can you elaborate process of collecting the signatures on a transaction? I also would like to replace users with particular peers so can AND endorsement be possible between particular peers inside an organization

Comment: The chaincode for operators tutorial has the process for signing chaincode to be installed. http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4noah.html

Comment: christo4ferris I have reframed my question can you answer it now?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation for [configuring an MSP](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html) (membership service provider):

> Defining one MSP to represent each division. This would involve
>   specifying for each division, a set of certificates for root CAs,
>   intermediate CAs, and admin Certs, such that there is no overlapping
>   certification path across MSPs. This would mean that, for example, a
>   different intermediate CA per subdivision is employed. Here the
>   disadvantage is the management of more than one MSPs instead of one,
>   but this circumvents the issue present in the previous approach. One
>   could also define one MSP for each division by leveraging an OU
>   extension of the MSP configuration.

After you have configured your MSP accordingly, then you would craft an [endorsement policy](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html) for the channel that stipulated that transactions needed to be endorsed by the three departments:

For example:

```
AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member')
```

where Org1, Org2 and Org3 are the identifiers for the departments.